# Invoking handler multiple times on file-input change

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I needed to create a button that will trigger an input-file and invoke the handler & AJAX when file was chosen:

```
<template>
<button id="ImportExcelBtn" type="button" class="ladda-button" data-color="mint" data-style="zoom-out" data-size="sm">
    <span class="ladda-label">Import Excel</span>
    <div class="hidden">
        <input type="file" id="fileUpload" @change="handleFileUpload">
    </div>
</button>
```

```
<script>
export default {
    props: {
        tablename: String,
        modelname: String
    },
    data: function() {
        return {
            recursive: true,
            file: {}
        }
    },
    methods: {
        handleFileUpload: function(e) {
            var self = this;
            self.file = e.target.files[0];
            self.importExcel();
        },
        importExcel: function() {
            var self = this;
            self.recursive = true;

            var bodyFormData = new FormData();
            bodyFormData.set('tablename', self.tablename);
            bodyFormData.append('file', self.file);

            Services.importExcel(bodyFormData).then(function(response) {
                if(response.data.status == 'failed'){
                    Global.ErrorMessages(response.data.messages);
                } else {
                    console.log('all right');
                }
            }).catch(function(error) {
                var error = Object.assign({}, error);
                console.log(error);
                Global.ErrorMessages(error.response);
            });
        }
    },
    mounted: function() {
        var self = this;
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#ImportExcelBtn').click(function() {
                if(self.recursive){
                    self.recursive = false;
                    $('#fileUpload').click();
                }
            });
        })
    }
}
```

At first go, this works perfectly, but if I chose another file to upload, than the handler isn't invoked when the file is chosen unless I click the button for the third time.
Please note that the input most be inside the button for system purposes, so taking it outside of the button and putting them both in a div is not an option...

Answer (score 0):

Check all the assignments of the **recursive**, please. If you click on the button and then cancel choosing a file that leads to the **recursive** would be **false** and afterwards the "click" handler does nothing.